# SQL joining column twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql:

```
select distinct 
p.products_image, 
pd.products_name, 
p.products_id, 
p.products_model, 
p.manufacturers_id, 
m.manufacturers_name, 
p.products_price, 
p.products_tax_class_id,
pd.products_viewed, 
group_concat(p2i.icons_id separator ",") as icons_ids, 
group_concat(pi.icon_class separator ",") as icon_class, 
IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price, 
IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price 

from products p 
left join specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id 
left join manufacturers m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
join products_description pd on p.products_id = pd.products_id 
join products_to_categories p2c on p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
INNER JOIN products_specifications ps7 ON p.products_id = ps7.products_id 
LEFT JOIN products_to_icon p2i on p.products_id = p2i.products_id 
LEFT JOIN products_icons pi on p2i.icons_id = pi.icons_id 

where p.products_status = '1' 
and pd.language_id = '1' 
AND ps7.specification in ('Cotton' , 'Fireproof' ) 
AND ps7.specifications_id = '7' 
AND ps7.language_id = '1' 
and p2c.categories_id = '21' 

group by p.products_id order by pd.products_name
```

This works perfectly when 1 product is only in 1 specification. But when a product has 2 specification like here( cotton & fireproof) the product_icons are being doubled.

I am selecting distinct, but because it is in 2 specifications, it is retrieving 2x the icons and I am not sure why (in my mind distinct should take care of that before selecting the icon IDs twice.)

What am I missing?

Update to clarify:

The results I get from the above query are shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n9aV.png

note the column icon_id for the 3rd row is showing the same icon_ids twice 5,1,5,1

My goal is to only have those IDs shown once so it should be 5,1

The more specifications I select, the more chance there will be even more repetition due to products belonging to several different specifications.

To clarify further here are some sample images of the products_to_icons and products_icons tables

Products_to_icons: http://i.imgur.com/gBhlCri.png
products_icons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J59bX.png

Comment: Nothing - that's the nature of the data. It would be like saying "i have 2 accounts, i want to see both accounts, but i only want to see one line". that's not possible - there are 2 account numbers and you're going to see both if you're selecting them

Comment: but I am seeing the actualy product only once (which is what I want) but the icons that go with the product are appearing twice.

Comment: Can you post an example result of your data?

Comment: Sure. Not sure the best way to post it so here is a screenshot of some data. Note the third row is the item in both specifications: http://i.imgur.com/aD6JM0q.png

Comment: Distinct is going to give you unique results across all columns returned. If you want to only see a single icon you need to use a query with less columns that provide you with uniqueness on whatever value you're using for your icon. If you want to expand out from there you can use whatever columns you used to get uniqueness at your icon level and use those columns as a kind of primary key back against your "full" query to get all the records associated with the icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have a group concatination going on, but no actual group by to use as it's basis.  How does the query know to break the groups to give you the multiple accounts you are looking for.

Comment: I get what you are saying but can't think of a solution

Comment: @Sackling, what is it you are actually looking for.  Update your question and provide a few sample records of the key tables and how the impact of your GROUP_CONCAT() should be applied.  Where are you expecting 1 vs 2 records to appear and what they SHOULD look like (or close TO what you expect).

Comment: Ok I will try to do that and clarify